# Retrieve data in combobox from SQL Server in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, relational

I have a database column, `Province=(Punjab, Sindh, Blochistan, Sarhad)` and other database table `City=Fsd, Lahore, Multan`, etc, and I have another database table `city=Chiniot, Khushab, Tando, Adam, Khan`, etc. Also another two more columns of city because I have four provinces, so I have four city tables.

If I select in `combobox1` `province=punjab`, it should show Punjab cities in `combobox2` like `punjab=Fsd,Lahore,Multan` etc. Same as another column when I select province "Sindh" in `combobox1` then show all Sindh cities, like this `sindh=Chinot, Khushab, Tando, Adam, Khan`, etc.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065-Master-Detail-(Parent-Child)-Data-binding-(-NET-2-0-WinForms)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is quite unclear, but it seems you have separate tables for cities in different provinces, and that's what is causing your problems. You should have only one table for cities and have the province as a column in that table. Then you can use the value from the combobox in the where clause for the cities table.